# Heroku DB not finding row after an edit changed the order of rows in DB

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, heroku

So this is interesting. I edited a user profile, and it moved in the database on heroku from what I can tell. It is now below row 15, and it has an id of 1. Here is the output from console, after connecting to the heroku db:

```
3 | Danyka     | Jones      | filip_nikolaus      | pass                                                         |        | https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jMRFTtoaM9I/U81C6LW8SMI/AAAAAAAABJU/6fI9fgRLVnQ/w426-h341/giving-hand.jpg                                                    | Add quote..                                                             |            |            | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.252597 | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.252597 | 
  4 | Angelina   | Kub        | ebbarempel          | pass                                                         |        | http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-iaXdpAip50o/TVaA1dfkLKI/AAAAAAAAADI/Lc58jQMLQtw/s320/happy3.png                                                                       | Add quote..                                                             |            |            | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.258762 | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.258762 | 
  5 | Bo         | Barton     | per_hammes          | pass                                                         |        | http://www.theunpluggedwoodshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/giving-tree-1.jpg                                                                                | Add quote..                                                             |            |            | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.26435  | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.26435  | 
  6 | Tristian   | Vandervort | ulf                 | pass                                                         |        | http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-iaXdpAip50o/TVaA1dfkLKI/AAAAAAAAADI/Lc58jQMLQtw/s320/happy3.png                                                                       | Add quote..                                                             |            |            | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.269916 | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.269916 | 
  7 | Bert       | Cartwright | annaschinner        | pass                                                         |        | https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jMRFTtoaM9I/U81C6LW8SMI/AAAAAAAABJU/6fI9fgRLVnQ/w426-h341/giving-hand.jpg                                                    | Add quote..                                                             |            |            | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.275477 | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.275477 | 
  8 | Lina       | Shanahan   | martin              | pass                                                         |        | http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-iaXdpAip50o/TVaA1dfkLKI/AAAAAAAAADI/Lc58jQMLQtw/s320/happy3.png                                                                       | Add quote..                                                             |            |            | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.28096  | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.28096  | 
  9 | Laurel     | Greenholt  | hannahirthe         | pass                                                         |        | http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-iaXdpAip50o/TVaA1dfkLKI/AAAAAAAAADI/Lc58jQMLQtw/s320/happy3.png                                                                       | Add quote..                                                             |            |            | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.286482 | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.286482 | 
 10 | Victor     | Becker     | ingegerd_altenwerth | pass                                                         |        | https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jMRFTtoaM9I/U81C6LW8SMI/AAAAAAAABJU/6fI9fgRLVnQ/w426-h341/giving-hand.jpg                                                    | Add quote..                                                             |            |            | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.292822 | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.292822 | 
 11 | Devonte    | Borer      | ullabritt           | pass                                                         |        | http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-iaXdpAip50o/TVaA1dfkLKI/AAAAAAAAADI/Lc58jQMLQtw/s320/happy3.png                                                                       | Add quote..                                                             |            |            | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.298556 | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.298556 | 
 12 | guest      | guest      | guest               | $2a$10$ntdETJrdzHPwqEeq2Kqeme3DeU9zzi8mlz/WIUTWGWwX2ijs5vkpO |        | http://img03.deviantart.net/3e34/i/2011/227/8/c/epik_face_by_epikfaceplz-d46p2on.png                                                                            |                                                                         |            |            | 2015-09-03 14:48:22.145592 | 2015-09-03 14:49:26.494595 | 
 13 | Linda      | Marie      | lindaM              | $2a$10$wOlYIjTVHkHReXMlcpHNReLM/V4tMTaItnNKhuRKgc2gVwlaA9r6e |        | http://tremendouswallpapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/quaker-parrots-1920x1200.jpg                                                                         |                                                                         |            |            | 2015-09-04 18:01:33.644988 | 2015-09-10 04:28:42.886892 | 
 15 | Linda      | Gaiud    | codemom             | $2a$10$J..1/Kyx3isJTkAJv11bf.5/DYQccXBonf9ji6U4v/szYE3Dfm89S |        | https://www.denverlibrary.org/files/css_code.jpg                                                                                                                |                                                                         |            |            | 2015-09-08 01:59:28.34503  | 2015-09-10 04:31:01.938624 | 
  1 | admin      | admin      | admin               | $2a$10$os7EetTB/e.Lfarbvt/BFO1SW.SDC9tkaE5zlprvsmF1BaKniSWi6 |        | https://scontent-lga1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfa1/v/t1.0-9/11119092_10206950218382306_4406697530463059534_n.jpg?oh=3b6578dc010d0ef918008fd5b96b2e18&oe=566808E1 | No one is useless in this world who lightens the burdens of another. \r+|            |            | 2015-09-02 05:37:35.146649 | 2015-09-12 02:52:15.04786  | t
    |            |            |                     |                                                              |        |                                                                                                                                                                 | - Charles Dickens                                                       |            |            |                            |                            | 
(13 rows)
```

For some reason when I click on that users name, instead of taking me to that profile, I get an error that the page can not be found despite it obviously existing in the DB. Here is what the url looks like when it hits that route:

```
https://boiling-stream-6729.herokuapp.com/users/1
```

the controller is pretty standard:

```
def show
            @user = User.find(params[:id])
            @allContributions = Payment.where(user_id: @user.id).to_a
            @userContributions =[];
                @allContributions.each{|c| @userContributions << Project.find(c.project_id)}
            @allContributions
        end
```

ANY other profile I go to, I don't have this problem, so I can only conclude it is because it has been shifted down in the db. I do not however understand what that would matter, or what I should do about it. Any input as to what is happening as well as what to do is appreciated!

Comment: What is the error message that you see in your heroku log? You should check that first. As I can see your show method doing a bunch of things, I am sure something is failing because it can't find some related resource. Your heroku log should tell you about that.

Comment: it says it can't find a project with an id of 7. i guess it is breaking at that point not the user's id, i hadn't noticed that before.

Comment: Yes, so its failing in this line: `@allContributions.each{|c| @userContributions << Project.find(c.project_id)}`.

Comment: your right. is there a clean way to check if the project still exists before trying to log it, and should it be written in the controller, or as a conditional in the view? what would be the best way to do that?

Comment: The logic should go in your controller, you can simply check if the `c.project_id` is present, then do: `Project.find(c.project_id)` otherwise not.

Comment: HolyMoly, Let me know if you have any other question. Thanks :)

Comment: thank you! it looks like deleting completed projects is not the way to go, rather I should just deactivate and archive them somehow, as I will need to reference them later at different points in the user history and for user statistical purposes. lesson learned! lol! thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check your `heroku log` first. As I can see your `show` method is doing a bunch of things, I am sure something is failing because it can't find some related resource. Your `heroku log` should tell you about that. In such cases, it's always best to check the log first to see the exact error message.

Comment: @HolyMoly, along with this you should also use [`exception_notification`](https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification) to know about exceptions happening in your application. Since they come from odd places all the time, it's useful to keep a track of where the hell is breaking loose :D